Seed data into api from using npm run script
How to send API call body in batches using type script?
I have a large array of numbers, and my api call cannot handle it all. I need to send the body in batches to the POST call
here is my code
const body = "{
    "arrayOfNum": [1,26,38,4,57,6,77,8,9,3333,55,3,55, ...etc]}"
export class Test {
    async test1() : Promise<void> {
        const response = await fetch(`${url}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `key=${API_KEY}`} 
        });
  }

calling function "testFunc.ts":
const test = new Test();
test.test1();

I can't use await in my calling function as I will be running this function from npm run testFunc

Is body an object or a string? It's not clear from the code you've provided. Are there other properties besides arrayOfNum?

Break the array into chunks and iterate those
const init = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    authorization: `key=${API_KEY}`,
  },
};
const chunkSize = 10; // or whatever makes sense

for (let i = 0; i < body.arrayOfNum.length; i += chunkSize) {
  const chunk = body.arrayOfNum.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    ...init,
    body: JSON.stringify({ arrayOfNum: chunk }),
  });
  
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
  }
}


I can't have await inside a for loop!

You certainly can. This is all inside your async test1 method
